# Navigate from one user control to another

Tags: c#, wpf, button, redirect

I have 2 user control page , theres a button in the first user control page that leads to another user control page , in asp.net , i know we can do this by response.redirect but in WPF i can't seems to find a way to do this . ]

i tried :

```
 NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        nav.Navigate(new Uri("Story.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

i also tried :

```
  Story test = new Story();
        test.ShowPage();
```

But theres an error with ShowPage , it says no definition for it . The above 2 codes does not work .

i have a page transition in the main window , i am displaying many user control page in that page transition . so i am trying to navigate between user control page in the page transition using buttons in the user control page

Comment: Did you get an error with the first example?

Comment: There is no error in the error list but it just crashes

Comment: When i debug , the nav is null

Comment: Have you tried using the static [`NavigationService.Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591053.aspx) method? e.g. `NavigationService.Navigate(uri)`.

Comment: u mean NavigationService.Navigate(story.xaml) ?

Comment: I am having same trouble here... any solution?

Comment: @lucaConfa its because i am using a library from other source ( page transition ) . so i had to pagetransition.ShowPage(pagename) to navigate them .